# Blank page in Inertia.js - no error in console

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I have been trying for 8 hours or so to get Inertia.js to work with Laravel and VueJS. What I get is a blank page with no error messages in the console (both the front-end and back-end consoles actually). What I have instead is a blank page and a tab with the loading animation running infinitely.

I searched on the Internet for an answer. I have found nothing that really helps.

What I'm trying to achieve is to get a result similar to the YouTube tutorial I'm using (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XEW2d2XHkAk).

---

Here is the content of the web.php file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

//
Route::get("/hello", function () {
    return inertia("Hello");
});
```

---

Here is the content of the app.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue'
import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress'

InertiaProgress.init()

createInertiaApp({
  resolve: name => require(`./Pages/${name}`),
  setup({ el, App, props }) {
    new Vue({
      render: h => h(App, props),
    }).$mount(el)
  },
})
```

---

Here is the content of the Kernel.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\HandleInertiaRequests::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    ];
}
```

---

Here is the content of the app.blade.php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="{{ mix('/css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    @inertia
  </body>
</html>
```

---

Here is the content of the Hello.vue file:

```
<template>
    <div>hi there i am the hello page</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {};
</script>
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Someone I know found the answer.

So I was getting confused between these two commands:

```
npm run watch
```

versus

```
php artisan serve
```

The browser would open a tab with the app running on port 3000. So all I needed to do was to change the port in the browser. For example:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello

Edit: So to sum it all up, you use "npm run watch" to make sure your app is always up to date in the browser" and you run "php artisan serve" to serve your app to the browser. You run the two commands, but you have to use the port provided to you after running the "php artisan serve" command.

Comment: strangely it works with php artisan serve, but not when accessing the app via localhost/my-app/public with my LAMP stack but made it work only by making a virtual host for the project