# Blank page when I try to set up Laravel + InertiaJS + Svelte

Tags: laravel, svelte, inertiajs

I tried following both the Inertia documentation and [this](https://paste.laravel.io/343907cc-79a8-429e-aebd-2b3a1b41bbb2) but I'm getting a blank page when I boot up the local server (yes I ran both npm run dev and php artisan serve)

Comment: This is probably not nearly enough information.

Comment: @H.B. what more information do I need to give? I made a fresh laravel 9 installation, set up inertia + svelte and made a page, that page isn't loading.

Comment: Show the relevant code, configs and look for errors in logs or console output. If there are errors they can help you fix the issue yourself, if you do not manage to do so, include them in the question and explain what you have tried to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

based on nearly not enough information :

if your browser has adblocker, such brave browser,, try to disable them,, then reload,,

Answer (score 0):

I suggest making sure you are using the correct port number. This issue really sounds similar to [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68776133/blank-page-in-inertia-js-no-error-in-console).

Comment: if you think the question is the same, you should flag for duplicate closure.

Comment: @starball I think the issue might be **similar**, but I cannot be absolutely certain. This is more a hypothesis than a certitude.